# How to uninstall git installed from the source?

Tags: centos, git, centos6, uninstall

I installed the git using [this article](http://kb.liquidweb.com/install-git-on-centos-5/). Now I want to uninstall the git. How to do it?

Comment: Do you still have the source code which you downloaded and did `make install` with?

Comment: Yes, I have  the source code

Comment: What is the output of 'make uninstall' ?  Not all Makefiles have this option, but many do.

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.

Comment: why -1? explain

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/Z-aY34jlxD8).

**UPDATED 2.11.2012**

If you were smart enough and used some non-standard prefix when
configured Git so that it has been installed under a specific hierarchy,
like under /opt/git, then just delete that hierarchy, recursively.

If not, then you could go like this:

1) Fetch the source tarball of exactly the version you built and
   installed, unpack.

2) Configure it exactly like you did with the original install with
   regard to installation locations (prefix, exec-prefix etc);
   supposedly you should just not override anything.

3) Create a temporary directory to perform installation, like this:
   $ mkdir /var/tmp/git

4) Install Git passing a proper DESTDIR variable to make:
   $ make DESTDIR=/var/tmp/git install
   The Git hierarchy will end up created under that temporary directory.

5) Use the created hierarchy to decide which files to delete under
   the real hierarchy ("/" itself).

The last step is where "the magic" happens so it bears more explanation.
For instance, you could run

```
$ find /var/tmp/git -type f -printf '/%P\n' | xargs -n 10 rm -f
```

(as root) do delete the files installed by the first mis-installation
into the root filesystem.  The encantation above uses the /var/tmp/git
hierarchy to print the list of files found, but it replaces the
"/var/tmp/git" prefix in them with "/", so that the
"/var/tmp/git/usr/bin/git" in the output will end up listed as
"/usr/bin/git".  This list is then piped to `xargs` which runs `rm`
on the file names it reads in packs of ten (just to reduce the number of
invocations of `rm` by one order of magnitude).

After dealing with files, run

```
$ find /var/tmp/git -type d -printf '/%P\n'
```

to inspect the list of installed directories.  These require manual
approach so just look at the generated list and think which of them you
could safely `rmdir` from your system (these will be the directories
like "/usr/libexec/git" or something like this; you wouldn't probably
want to delete "/usr/share/man/mann" or something even if it's empty).

P.S.
In the future *never* install anything into a system by running
`make install`!  Most makefiles these days do not support "uninstall"
target as they are used to either installing into a private scratch
location for testing or to make a package (.rpm, .deb etc) and then the
package manager takes care of cleaning up.
If you need to install something, try to find an official package or try
to backport another official package from a more recent version of
your OS, if available.
As the last resort, try using the `checkinstall` tool which tries to
create a binary package out of your `make install` run.  This sucks,
but still better than bare `make install`.

Comment: Please expand some of the details found there. Bit-rot happens, and when that does this answer becomes useless.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer

Comment: Respect. it works

Comment: Summary: `./configure`. `sudo make && sudo make DESTDIR=/var/tmp/git install`. `sudo find /var/tmp/git -type f -printf '/%P\n' | sudo xargs -n 10 rm -f`

Answer (score 3):

I just went though 2691 lines of Makefile. Indeed no make uninstall. Drat.

In that case a workaround might be to use the `make rpm` option. Install the rpm (overwriting all installed files, which should be identical to the already installed files). Then de-install the rpm.

In all future cases build a package (RPM, yum, whatever). It makes maintenance so much easier.

Comment: Except typically `make install` puts stuff in prefix `/usr/local` whereas the rpm/deb/your-package-here run `./configure` with different parameters so that the files they install end up with prefix `/usr`.

Comment: I'm newbie in the CentOS. What command should I run? Can you explain more, please

Comment: I ran the `make rpm` command. What should I do the next?

Comment: Start with `man rpm` or `'rpm --help`. It will probably tell you to use `rpm -i packagename.rpm`. However it might be best to ask the sysadmin at umbrella-web to help you. There is only so much we can do from a distance.